# Keep getting error message about avoiding wrapping code in act after wrapping code in act

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing

I'm writing a test for a component that uses a search form. This is in `search.js` and it imports a Formik form from another file `searchForm.js`.

I've written this unit test which passes. I've based it off an example in [the react testing docs here](https://testing-library.com/docs/example-input-event/).

Every time I run it I get this error, which confuses me since I've wrapped all the code in act?

```
console.error
    Warning: An update to Formik inside a test was not wrapped in act(...).
    
    When testing, code that causes React state updates should be wrapped into act(...):
    
    act(() => {
      /* fire events that update state */
    });
    /* assert on the output */
    
    This ensures that you're testing the behavior the user would see in the browser. Learn more at https://reactjs.org/link/wrap-tests-with-act
```

```
import React from "react";
import { render, screen, act, fireEvent } from "@testing-library/react";
import Search from "./search.js";
import { ChakraProvider } from "@chakra-ui/react";


test("Search form input", () => {
  act(() => {
    const setup = () => {
      const utils = render(
        <ChakraProvider>
          <Search />
        </ChakraProvider>
      );
      const searchTermsInput = utils.getByLabelText("search terms input");
      return {
        searchTermsInput,
        ...utils,
      };
    };
    const { searchTermsInput } = setup();

    fireEvent.change(searchTermsInput, { target: { value: "23" } });
  });
  expect(screen.getByLabelText("search terms input").value).toBe("23");
});
```

Comment: That warning is actually telling you: "So the `act` warning from React is there to tell us that something happened to our component when we weren't expecting anything to happen.". That quote was taken from [this blog](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/fix-the-not-wrapped-in-act-warning). [Here](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/fix-the-not-wrapped-in-act-warning#how-to-fix-the-act-warning) is how you can fix it.

Answer (score 0):

As per the comment above, fixed this by rewriting the test as follows to allow for some other changes to state that happen in the `search.js` component which weren't part of this specific test.

```
import React from "react";
import { render, screen, act, fireEvent, waitFor } from "@testing-library/react";
import Search from "./search.js";
import { ChakraProvider } from "@chakra-ui/react";


test("Search form input", async () => {
  act(() => {
    const setup = () => {
      const utils = render(
        <ChakraProvider>
          <Search />
        </ChakraProvider>
      );
      const searchTermsInput = utils.getByLabelText("search terms input");
      return {
        searchTermsInput,
        ...utils,
      };
    };
    const { searchTermsInput } = setup();

    fireEvent.change(searchTermsInput, { target: { value: "23" } });
  });
  expect(screen.getByLabelText("search terms input").value).toBe("23");
  // This removes a code not wrapped in act warning triggered by other state events
  // namely setQuery which is called after adding search term inputs
  await waitFor(() => screen.queryByText(/Find results/))});
```